# What Magento Version (2.x) support Multiple Inventory System

Tags: magento2, products, inventory, quantity, multiple

I have more than one store, i need to update more than one store inventory for same product. May i know what Magento Version (2.x series) support multiple inventory System.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2.3

https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-2.3-new-tools-fuel-your-growth-2019

> MULTI-SOURCE INVENTORY As merchants grow and evolve, so do the ways
>   they sell, store, and deliver their products. Multi-Source Inventory
>   (MSI) helps merchants improve operational efficiency by managing
>   inventory across multiple physical locations from within the Magento
>   admin. Additionally, merchants can:
>
> Assign products and quantities to each fulfillment source, such as
>   warehouses, stores, distribution centers or third-party drop shippers.

Comment: Can you pls give me clarify about @IgorMinyaylo statement pls.

Comment: If you want to use this feature Magento version installed should be >= 2.3

Comment: Okay. Ver 2.3.0 only available for download in Magneto. And i just testing.

Answer (score 1):

MSI is supported since Magento 2.3

Magento 2.1.X and 2.2.X series would not have support of Multi-Source Inventory functionality